# Comment on the plots of two fitted densities on a histogram

Tags: statistics, gamma-function, parameter-estimation, gamma-distribution

What possible comments can I draw on this following plot? It contains plot of two fitted densities. One estimating the parameters using MLE and other using MME, that I calculated from a set of data following gamma distribution. Will "both method gives almost the same plot." be enough as description?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH6yP.png)

Comment: According to the most commonly used criteria, MME's as slightly less accurate than MLE's, so I would a gamma density curve fit with MLE is likely closer to the truth than the one based on the MME. But as you say, there is hardly any difference between the two curves in your specific situation. Fir a really helpful discussion, you might show the MMEs and MLE's of the gamma parameters and say why you want to estimate the PDF. // Depending on circumstances and goals, maybe you should include a kernel density estimator  (KDE) of the PDF based on the data, and not worry about parameter estimation.

Answer (score 0):

Comment continued:

When the sample size is large, any consistent estimator should help
to estimate the density of the population.

Below we use R to sample $n = 100\,000$ observations at random from
$\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape} = \alpha = 4, \mathrm{rate}= \lambda = 0.1),$
For this distribution, $\mu = \alpha/\lambda$ and $\sigma^2 = \alpha/\lambda^2.$
Thus the MLEs are $\tilde \alpha = \bar X^2/S^2$ and
$\tilde\lambda = \bar X/ S^2.$

In particular, for our sample $\tilde \alpha = 3.9845,$ which is very close
to the population value $\alpha = 4$ and $\tilde \lambda = 0.09938,$ which is very close to $\lambda - 0.1.$

```
set.seed(519)
x = rgamma(10^5, 4, .1)
mean(x);  var(x)
[1] 40.09246
[1] 403.4163
shape=mean(x)^2/var(x); shape
[1] 3.984484
rate = mean(x)/var(x);  rate
0.09938236
```

Therefore, we should expect that the density function (solid orange curve) for
$\mathsf{Gamma}(\hat \alpha, \hat \lambda)$ should fit the
histogram of the data quite well, which it does. [The fit would look
better if I had used more bins to make the histogram, but then
the tops of the bars would obscure the density curve.]

However, the default [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) in R from the procedure `density` (dashed purple)
is almost identical to the density curve based on MMEs, within the resolution
of the graph.

```
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
curve(dgamma(x, shape, rate), add=T, col="orange")
lines(density(x), lwd=2, col="purple", lty="dashed")
```

[image]

This demonstration is not to denigrate MMEs (much MLEs), but to
show that KDEs based on large samples can provide extremely good estimates of
density functions.

---

*Note:* With only $n = 500$ observations, we have $\tilde\alpha = 3.93, \tilde \lambda = 0.097,$ and the plot is as below. The dotted black
like is for the true population density (known here only because
this is a simulation experiment). Tick marks along the horizontal axis show locations of data values.

The density based on MMEs and the KDE are
presented as in the plot above. For samples of small or moderate size, as here, the KDE is often nearer to the shape of the histogram and the curve based on parameter
estimation is often nearer to the actual population density.

[image]